# How to give condition in dynamic content of stored procedure activity in ADF

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have a stored procedure to which I pass two parameters: **TableName** and **year**
and then I calculate the fiscal year according to which my records will be truncated.
Here is my stored procedure:

```
create proc [truncate_fiscal_year] 
@tablename varchar(max),@year varchar(max)
as
begin
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql='delete from'+' '+@tablename+' '+'where Date='+@year
exec(@sql)
end
```

Now, i create a stored procedure activity on Azure Data factory and pass this stored procedure.
Using Import parameters, I imported the parameters but I am not able to understand what condition to give in the year parameter so that it will return the current fiscal year to the **year** parameter:

[image: Here is the pipeline]

Comment: **WARNING:** Your SQL is *wide* open to SQL injection. This is *extremely* dangerous. **Never** inject unsanitised strings into a dynamic statement. Object names should be properly quoted (using `QUOTENAME`) and the defined as the correct data type (`sysname`) , and parameters should be **parametrised** and, again, *also* the correct data type (what "year" is 2 billion characters long?).

Comment: @Larnu I will correct that but first help me with the question

Comment: I would suggest that if you have similar columns on many tables then you probably have a design issue

Answer (score 0):

If you want set the parameter year with current fiscal year( now is 2021), maybe you could build the expression like this: `@substring(utcnow(),0,4)`
[image]

The expression will return the current fiscal year: 2019. Please correct me if I misunderstand you.

Comment: Thanks for your help  but I am facing problem since it is showing error, type conversion failed to int

Comment: @user123 what's the error? What have you done? Your question didn't say you get the error.

Comment: No, i tried your solution and then it is showing error. The error is : "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2021-03-31' to data type int."

Comment: @user123 did you use the same expression as mine? The key is what's your fiscal year look like, '2021' or '2021-03-31'? And what's the data type did you set?

Comment: I solved this error, its working now. But this is according to the current date, and I want to calculate according to the condition to calculate fiscal year. could you help with that

Comment: @user123 glad to hear that! What's the calculate rule or what's the condition? Not very sure if it can be achieve with the [expression language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions). By the way, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.